# Getting 'Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB' while loading huge data from MongoDB to spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to create a spark dataframe from Cosmos DB (MongoDB API). But I am getting an exception:

*com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16501: 'Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB. Please consider adding more filters to reduce the query response size.' on server ******.documents.azure.com:10255. The full response is {"_t": "OKMongoResponse", "ok": 0, "code": 16501, "errmsg": "Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB. Please consider adding more filters to reduce the query response size.", "$err": "Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB. Please consider adding more filters to reduce the query response size."}*

Is there any way we can handle this: I don't have any control over MongoDB. So I cannot increase the RUs.

Below is my code to read data from mongo db.

```scala
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName(APP_NAME)
      .master(sparkMaster)
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.database", database_name)
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection", collection_name).getOrCreate()

def getReadConfig(uri: String, database: String, collection: String): ReadConfig = {
    ReadConfig(Map(
      "spark.mongodb.input.uri" -> uri,
      "spark.mongodb.input.database" -> database,
      "spark.mongodb.input.collection" -> collection,
      "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred",
      "spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.shardkey" -> MONGO_INPUT_SHARDKEY_VALUE
    ), Some(ReadConfig(getSparkSession.sparkContext)))
  }

val readConfig = getReadConfig("uri", "database_name", "collection_name")

def getSubmissionsByIdRangePipeline(surveyId: String): Seq[Document] = {
    Seq(Document.parse("{ $match: { partition_key: " + "partition_value" + ", id: '" + "id" + "' } }"))}

case class Submission(survey_id: String,
                      submitter_win: String,
                      answers: List[SurveyAnswer],
                      submitted_on: Timestamp)

val submissionsChunkRDD: MongoRDD[Document] = MongoSpark
          .load(sparkSession, readConfig)
          .withPipeline(getSubmissionsByIdRangePipeline(surveyId))

val df = submissionsChunkRDD.toDF[Submission]()

df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been there with the Cosmos DB using Mongo Wire Protocol v3.2. [This](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16997/) is the GitHub issue link.

In order to resolve this issue, you need not increase RUs but instead look to filter out the output dataset more. There could be two ways of doing that-

1. The filtering logic seems to be part of your code. So better to add some additional filter (maybe submission date range) to the query and get a reduced result set.
2. Also, if there are any specific properties that you need from the result set, you could project only those while querying so that the document size in result set gets reduced.

As per [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16997/#issuecomment-576797434) GitHub issue, If you can get the Cosmos DB to upgrade to v3.6 wire protocol, this issue should get resolved. [These](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-version-upgrade) steps from MSFT doc can be followed for the upgrade.